# Convert directory structure to json?

Tags: python, json

I want to convert a project hierarchy with some properties for each class or package in a JSON dictionary. for example

I am using python for this. Can anyone please give me some basic outline. How I can implement this.Thank you. thus i want something like:

```
a = package, a.b = package, a.b.c = class, a.b.d = class

j_string = {
    "my_data": {
        "a": "info": {},
        "b": {
            "info": {},
            "c": {
                "info": {}
            },
            "d": {
                "info": {}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `import jason; jason.loads(j_string)` - But your string is by design broken since it's encapsulated with `"` and you haven't escaped the inner `"` slements. I suggest using `'` around the string.

Comment: who is jason? - `import json`

Comment: Perhaps something like [os.walk()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.walk)

Comment: Actually data is not from my system so I just get the paths as strings. i have to parse it using '.'delimiter

Comment: By "project hierarchy" do you mean a collection of directories of directories and files on disk? How you do discover properties... like how do you know a is a "package" and a.b.d is a "class"?

Comment: I get it from a tool. For instance let consider that there is a string delimited by '.'  and I have to build hierarchy of that based on delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

try to use `pkgutil.walk_packages` combine with `importlib.import_module`.

```
def get_all_module_of_a_package(pkg_name):
    pkg = importlib.import_module(pkg_name)
    for importer, name, is_pkg in pkgutil.walk_packages(pkg.__path__, pkg.__name__ + '.'):
        if is_pkg:
            continue
        print name # I just print them, you can build a dict you desired
        # do some other things (if you want to get member of a module)
        # use inspect.getmembers



>>> get_all_module_of_a_package('json')
json.decoder
json.encoder
json.scanner
json.tests.test_check_circular
json.tests.test_decode
json.tests.test_default
json.tests.test_dump
json.tests.test_encode_basestring_ascii
json.tests.test_fail
json.tests.test_float
json.tests.test_indent
json.tests.test_pass1
json.tests.test_pass2
json.tests.test_pass3
json.tests.test_recursion
json.tests.test_scanstring
json.tests.test_separators
json.tests.test_speedups
json.tests.test_tool
json.tests.test_unicode
json.tool
```